# How can we bounce the dock icon on the Mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos

How can we bounce the dock icon of our application?

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `requestUserAttention:` from [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428358-requestuserattention). The  `NSRequestUserAttentionType` allows you to specify whether the Dock icon will bounce once or until the application is activated.

Answer (score 8):

sorry it works... my focus was on my application when I test it... Its works when my focus is not on application

```
[NSApp requestUserAttention:NSCriticalRequest];
```

Is any way to bounce the icon even focus on application...

Comment: I think you don't have to request user attention if your application is active as the user is, well, using your application.
Maybe you should consider using the Growl framework to display visual notifications.

Comment: Swift 3: `NSApp.requestUserAttention(.criticalRequest)` There is also: `.informationalRequest` Which seems to only bounce a few times. @Laurent Etiemble More subtle.